# how to add a text in email editext after it encounters a "@" symbol in android

Tags: android

I am developing an app,in login screen when i enter the email id the edittext must automatically append some text after encountering a "@" symbol.I tried using addtextchangelistner it dosent work.

Comment: add `TextWatcher` to the edittext

Comment: Please show some code that "didn't work" so that we can know what you did wrong and how to fix it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use TextWatcher like below for that.

```
edit.addOnTextChangeListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   void afterTextChanged(Editable var1){
      if (var1.getText().toString().endsWith("@")) {
          edit.append("xyz.com");
      }
   }

   @Override
   void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence var1, int var2, int var3, int var4) {

   }

   @Override
   void onTextChanged(CharSequence var1, int var2, int var3, int var4) {

   }
});
```